# Git Remote Origin: using git@github.com vs https://github.com

Tags: github

By default, git sets `[remote "origin"]` to `url = git@github.com:me/myrepo.com.git` and when running `git push -u origin main` , I'm getting the following error: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey)`.

It works after setting `url = https://github.com/me/myrepo.com.git` instead.

So, why doesn't it work with the default settings?
What should I do to be able to use the default settings?